# Solve $ y''\theta(t) = \sin(\theta(t))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is the following:

$$ y''\theta(t) = \sin(\theta(t))$$

This is an easy Heaviside differential equation.

This is how I have tried to solve it:

$$ y''* \theta(t) = y'* \theta(t) ' = y' * \delta(t) = y'$$

(since everything convoluted with the derivative of the Heaviside unit step function is the other factor)

This means that:

$$ y' =  \sin(\theta(t)) $$

and

$$ y' =  \theta(t) \sin(1) $$
(since $\theta(t) = 1$ for $t>0$, but it is equivalent with the last step).

$$ y=t \cdot \sin(1)\cdot \theta(t) + C.$$

However, the correct answer to the problem is:

$$ y(t) = t \cdot \sin (1) \cdot θ(t)  + C_1t + C_2.$$

Which is very similar to mine, but how did they get those extra constants?

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that $ (y'' * \theta)(t) = y'(t) $. Correctly you have
$$ (y'' * \theta)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y''(t-s)\theta(s)ds = \int_0^\infty y''(t-s)ds = y'(t) - \lim_{s\rightarrow -\infty} y'(s)$$
Let us denote $C_1:=\lim_{s\rightarrow -\infty} y'(s)$. We have
$$ y'(t) = \sin(\theta(t)) + C_1$$
which leads to the correct answer.

Comment: $  \int_0^\infty y''(t-s)ds = y'(t) - \lim_{s\rightarrow -\infty} y'(s) $ , what reasoning did you use here to get the answer to this integral? Very thankful for your help, and I understand the problem a lot better now!

Comment: $y''(t-s) = \frac{d}{ds}\big(-y'(t-s)\big)$, so $$ \int_0^M y''(t-s) ds = \int_0^M \frac{d}{ds}\big(-y'(t-s)\big)  ds= -y'(t-M)+y'(t)$$ $$ \int_0^\infty y''(t-s) ds = -\big(\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}y'(t-M)\big)+y'(t) = -\big(\lim_{s\rightarrow-\infty}y'(s)\big)+y'(t)$$